# Get a single string attribute from my user's extended model

Tags: django

i think my question it's simple, but i'm new and i cannot figure it out.

I have a user default Django model and my extended user model, and in my views.py i just want to get my logged user's address like a single string, i have been trying with different ways using (UserProfile.objects.values/filter/get etc...) but i just get errors.

Thank you for your time!

Models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="profile_imgs")
    address = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=150)
    curp = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=18)
```

Views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='log')
def test(request):

address = "answer"

context = {
        'address': address,
    }

    return render(request, "test.html", context)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the address from the request user's instance but you need to add a `related_name` to the user field in `UserProfile` model.

see below:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile')
```

after that fetch the request user's address in the view functions as follows:

```
@login_required(login_url='log')
def test(request):
    context = {
       'address': request.user.user_profile.address,
    }
    return render(request, "test.html", context)
```

Comment: Didn't know about this, thank u so much, is working fine and it was what i needed!

Comment: You can even extend the user model without creating new model and just by adding new fields to the existing one. Refer to this: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractuser

Comment: Great! i actually wanted to do that from the beginning, and in that case, how would be the way to call the same "address" attribute for example, in my views.py?

Comment: you can do that simply by getting the `address` attribute of the user instance - `request.user.address`.

Comment: I'm getting it all now,  thank u so much for your time, this will definitely be useful!